# Click elsewhere and checkbox is ticked/unticked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

So I have a piece of code to create a table with some data in it. The first column contains checkboxes, other columns are just regular data.

What I want is that when I click anywhere on a random row (except for header), that entire row's background is turning into yellow (initially white) and the checkbox in that row is ticked. If I click again, everything in the row back to its normal (white row and unticked checkbox).

When I click right at the checkbox, everything acts as expected. However, when I click elsewhere, only the background is changed. I have checked the `checked` attribute of the checkbox and it is changed whenever I click (which is like normal). I don't know why this happens. I have looked through many posts with similar issues but it is not helped. I am only a beginner at Javascript and HTML. Please help me with this. Thank you very much!

```js
function changeColorRow(number) {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[number]
  var curr_check = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox").checked
  if (!curr_check) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
    document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox").checked = true
  } else {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox").checked = false
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>List of companies</h1>
<table id="company">
  <tr>
    <th>Choose</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Website</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="changeColorRow(1)">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ECOPRO Co., Ltd</td>
    <td>http://www.ecoprovn.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="changeColorRow(2)">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>WAVINA.COM</td>
    <td>http://www.wavina.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Duplicate: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/v7ty0m1x/

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much. I will look through that duplicate link and submit duplicate review later

Comment: It's not necessary to review anything, you used `document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox").checked` which won't work because `document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")` returns a list of matching elements.

Comment: Oh right, thank you for pointing it out. Can I ask a small final question before closing this topic? When I set index to `document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")` by adding `[number - 1]`, nothing happens when I click at the checkbox (just like other answers). Why is that?

Comment: What's duplicate in the question?

Comment: It's because clicking the checkbox checks it, then your tr click handler unchecks it again. Even if you fix that, checking a box won't make the row yellow. See my fiddle for a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array like structure, You have to use index to get that particular element at that index.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")
```

You can get the index of the clicked row as

```
index = number - 1
```

```js
const allCheckbox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");

function changeColorRow(number) {
  const index = number - 1;
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[number]
  var curr_check = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")[index].checked

  if (!curr_check) elem.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
  else elem.style.backgroundColor = "white"

  allCheckbox[index].checked = !allCheckbox[index].checked
}

[...allCheckbox].forEach(cb => {
  cb.addEventListener("change", (e) => changeColorRow(parseInt(e.target.dataset.index)))
})
```

```css
tr {
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>List of companies</h1>
<table id="company">
  <tr>
    <th>Choose</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Website</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="changeColorRow(1)">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-index="1"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ECOPRO Co., Ltd</td>
    <td>http://www.ecoprovn.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="changeColorRow(2)">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-index="2"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>WAVINA.COM</td>
    <td>http://www.wavina.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When clicking an input, nothing happens

Comment: Thanks for your help. It fixes my current issue. But now, when I click at checkboxes, nothing happens, even the checkbox is not ticked. This feature worked before. Can you review your code please? Thank you very much!

Comment: Another broken snippet... also, this is a dupe.

Comment: @ChrisG I agree it is dupe of `what does getElementsByClassName returns`, but this is not the only problem OP is facing. It is one of multiple problems

Comment: That just means that the question needs to be edited, fixed or removed. Posting an answer suggests that this is a valid question. Helping OP is fine, but posting answers to bad questions will kill this website. Just post a comment instead, downvote, move on.